# JSF Servlet Causing weird behaviour

Tags: java, jsf, servlets

I have a servlet that's entire purpose is to redirect a person to a page based on the parameter passed into it. However when I redirect to a page, any button clicked will cause the page to redirect to my landing page.

Controller:

```
@WebServlet(name = "Case1Controller", urlPatterns = {"/C1Control"})
public class Case1Controller extends HttpServlet {

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        String jsf = request.getParameter("jsf");
        if(jsf.equalsIgnoreCase("V")) {
    response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL("AddVendor.jsf"));
        }
        if(jsf.equalsIgnoreCase("P")) {
    response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL("AddProduct.jsf"));
        }
        if(jsf.equalsIgnoreCase("O")) {
    response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL("POGenerator.jsf"));
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}


@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}


@Override
public String getServletInfo() {
    return "Short description";
}
```

}

usage:

```
 < ul>
      < m:MenuItem caption="Add Vendor" jsf="V"/>
      < m:MenuItem caption="Add Product" jsf="P"/>
      < m:MenuItem caption="Generate PO" jsf="O"/>
 < /ul>
```

the menu item control:

```
<!-- INTERFACE -->
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="caption" required="true"/>
    <cc:attribute name="jsf" required="true"/>
</cc:interface>

<!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
<cc:implementation>
    <h:outputLink value="/Info5059Case1/C1Control?jsf=#{cc.attrs.jsf}"> #{cc.attrs.caption}</h:outputLink>&nbsp;

</cc:implementation>
```

Comment: What is *landing page*? Try using either an `if-else if-else` ladder or putting an empty `return` statement immediately after `response.sendRedirect()`.

Comment: @lion, the if-else-if block didn't work. as for the landing page, its the add vendor page, accessed through AddVendor.jsf instead of C1Controller?jsf=V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is something in your button causing an exception to be thrown that you are not catching? This could cause the controller to redirect you.

Comment: Yeah, the button was throwing an exception, which seemed to be causing the redirect. Thanks